# Setting Cookie using pycurl, getting TypeError('invalid arguments to setopt',)

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies, pycurl

I am new to python I am trying to send session_id as a cookie using pycurl lib in python. Below is the code line.

```
reportcurl.setopt(pycurl.COOKIE, session_id)
```

Where "session_id" is a string. Not sure what I am doing wrong but it is working on Python version 2.7.2 but I am unable to make it run on Python 2.7.3.

Any idea what could be invalid argument in setopt fuction?

Appeciate for any help. Thanks

Comment: If you're new to python, I would humbly suggest you use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) module. Its API is much clearer and simpler. To set a cookie, you would simply do `>>> requests.get(url, cookies = {'session_id': ...})`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I wounder if I get to change whole approach instead for fixing one line.

Answer (score 0):

> Data that an application passes to PycURL, such as via setopt calls, must normally be byte strings appropriately encoded.

Make sure the session_id is in the correct format.

http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/unicode.html

Comment: Thanks Mark, let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Go it working by encoding

```
session_id.encode("utf-8")
```